# Best Stack Exchange site for asking about Bugzilla future development

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the best Stack Exchange site for asking about [Bugzilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugzilla) future development and forks?

I'd like to understand how the [original Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.org) (last release on 2018), [BMO](https://wiki.mozilla.org/BMO/How_to_Use_Bugzilla#BMO_vs_Bugzilla) (the Mozilla fork), [Bugzilla Harmony](https://github.com/bugzilla/harmony#readme) and maybe some other versions differ from each other and which one should choose.

Comment: How about the official bugzilla site?

Comment: Can you add one or more examples of such questions?

Comment: @Luuklag: Which "bugzilla site" should I use? There are several with different forks like [bugzilla.org](https://bugzilla.org), [bugzilla.mozilla.org](https://wiki.mozilla.org/BMO/How_to_Use_Bugzilla#BMO_vs_Bugzilla) and https://github.com/bugzilla/harmony#readme?

Comment: @P.Mort. - forgot Clay Shirky_q, I elaborated the question.

Comment: How is asking "which site to use" about "future development"?

Comment: If you want someone to recommend a bug tracker, [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) would be the closest but you'd need to have a **specific** set of criteria to be considered a quality question ([here's an example](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/46401/open-source-issue-bug-tracker-with-image-copy-paste-functionality-needed)), not a general "what's best". The "how do they differ" part would be off-topic altogether.

Comment: That seems to be the right site for the question. I posted [my question](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2960/76495) there. Thanks!

Comment: @gnat, it does not fully answer because Bugzilla communication is diverted to separate forums depending on the version / fork.

Comment: @haba713 the answer simply is, on both your question and the one linked by gnat, "not on SE".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Future development and forks ... that sounds like open-ended questions and/or discussions, and that's not what the Stack Exchange platform is for. I'm not familiar with Bugzilla but you could try the chat channel mentioned on [their website](https://www.bugzilla.org/support/).

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bugzilla/) has a [bugzilla] tag but it's (like all of Stack Overflow) focused on concrete (implementation) problems with current framework versions.

Comment: I elaborated the question. Different versions / forks have different sites and I'd like to send my question to some site that has participants with an objective point of view to different versions.